# EditText to search filter on Simpleadapter?

Tags: android

So I have a `SimpleAdapter` set up and I want to add an `editText` above it that you can enter your search query into and have the list update in real-time.

I know I can already `setTextFilterEnabled(true)` and force a keyboard popup. I was going to simply do that when you press an `editText` and just be done with it.

The problem I'm having is that the box that pops up with the letters when you search is really ugly and too big. It takes up literally 1/4 of the screen, covering your search results. Is there a way to customize this? Is there a way to use an `editText` for a `simpleAdapter` in this case so I can remove that box altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Tobias' answer was insightful, it did not answer my question and was fairly complex for what I needed to do. Rather than clearing and reloading the list each time, I opted to using a Filter in the array adapter that does all of that automatically:

[This is the article](http://www.mokasocial.com/2010/07/arrayadapte-filtering-and-you/) that helped me do it, and it was VERY useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `addTextChangedListener` with a `TextWatcher`.

```
Boolean[] isPresent;

ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {

                textLength = ed.getText().length();
                list.clear();
                isPresent = initIsPresentArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < tempList.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < (tempList[i].length() - (textLength - 1)); j++) {
                        if (textLength <= tempList[i].length()) {
                            if (isPresent[i] == false) {
                                if (ed.getText()
                                        .toString()
                                        .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                                (String) tempList[i]
                                                        .subSequence(
                                                                j,
                                                                (j + textLength)))) {
                                    list.add(tempCaseList.get(i));
                                    isPresent[i] = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (list.size() == 0) {
                        error.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.notFound));
                    } else {
                        error.setText("");
                    }

                    lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(History.this, list));
                }
            }
        });
```

And the method initIsPresentArray()

```
 public Boolean[] initIsPresentArray() {
            Boolean[] isPresent = new Boolean[tempCaseList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < isPresent.length; i++) {
                isPresent[i] = false;
            }
            return isPresent;
        }
```

As you may see, I don't do operation directly on the `ArrayList` containing the information, but I copy this `ArrayList` over to a temporary `ArrayList`, using this method

```
public ArrayList<Case> createTempList(ArrayList<Case> listOfCases) {

    ArrayList<Case> temporaryList = new ArrayList<Case>();

    for (Case c : listOfCases) {
        temporaryList.add(c);
    }

    return temporaryList;
}
```

Just add a comment if something is uncleared!

Comment: That certainly got complicated fast. I'll give this a try and let you know how it went!

Comment: Ran into a few roadblocks over the last week. I will get back to this and let you know if it worked as soon as I can, sorry!

Comment: Before I get started, this is instant right? Like the setTextFilterEnabled(true) one?

Comment: I also feel like theres a lot missing here. What is tempCaseList? Where is tempList declared?

Comment: `tempList` is the temporary List, which contains some `Objects` in my case a self defined class named `Case`, but it could be any type. `tempCaseList` is the `ListView` which holds an `ArrayList`